# Are their performance differences between querying inbound vs outbound edges on a graph database?

Tags: performance, graph, neo4j, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Say I have a vertices V() and K() and I have potential edges:

`V --isChildOf--> K`

`V <--isParentOf-- K`

If I'm looking for children of vertex V, are their performance differences between:

`V.out('isChildOf') vs V.in('isParentOf')?`

Database: NeptuneDb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cybersam answer for `Neptune` is not accurate.
According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/feature-overview-data-model.html#feature-overview-storage-indexing):

`If the number of distinct predicates in a graph becomes large, the default Neptune access strategy can become inefficient. In Gremlin, for example, an in() step where no edge labels are given, or any step that uses in() internally such as both() or drop(), may become quite inefficient.`

This can be mitigated by enabling OSGP Index Creation Using Lab Mode.

Comment: Just adding an observation that it is a recommended best practice when using TinkerPop enabled graphs to always specify the edge labels if possible to help the query engine efficiently filter out edges that are not of interest regardless of the graph DB being used.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

For `neo4j`, there is *no* performance difference between traversing inbound versus outbound relationships.

However, for `Neptune`, inbound relationships can be less efficient. As pointed out by @KafirDadosh, the [Neptune Graph Data Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/feature-overview-data-model.html) documentation states:

> If the number of distinct predicates in a graph becomes large, the
>   default Neptune access strategy can become inefficient. In Gremlin,
>   for example, an in() step where no edge labels are given, or any step
>   that uses in() internally such as both() or drop(), may become quite
>   inefficient.